# Probability Joint Density Question

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

Suppose $(X, Y )$ is uniformly distributed over the set $\{(x, y) : 0 < y + x < 2, 0 < x < 2\}$.

Find the joint density of $(X,Y)$ and marginal density of $F_Y(y)$.

I am having a tough time starting this problem as I don't know what to do with that function above. I know marginal density involves a double integral, but I cant even find joint density because the equation is throwing me off.

How should one begin this particular problem?

Comment: Uniformly distributed over a set $S$ means a density $f$ constant on $S$ and $0$ elsewhere. Try to find out how the set $S$ looks like here. Draw a picture.

Comment: The marginal **density** function involves a *single* integral, $f_Y(y)=\int_{?}^{?} f_{X,Y}(s,y)\operatorname d s$.  The marginal **cumulative distribution** function is the double integral: $F_Y(y)=\int_?^y\int_{?}^{?} f_{X,Y}(s,t)\operatorname d s\operatorname d t$ . Be sure of which you want.

Answer (score 0):

The joint density is 
$$f_{X,Y}(x,y)=\begin{cases}
1,& \text{ if } 0\le x,y \le 2 \text{ and } x+y \le 2 \\
0, & \text{ otherwise }\end{cases}$$
as shown below

[image]

By definition, the marginal density of $Y$ is

$$f_Y(y)=\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}f_{X,Y}(x,y)\ dx=\int_0^{2-y}\ \ \frac{1}{2}\ \ dx=\begin{cases}\frac{2-y}{2}&,\text{ if } 0\le y \le 2\\
0&, \text{ otherwise }.\end{cases}$$

Then the marginal cumulative distribution function of $Y$ is

$$F_Y(y)=\int_{-\infty}^y f_Y(u) \ du=\begin{cases}0&, \text{ if }y<0\\
\int_0^y\frac{2-u}{2}du=y-\frac{y^2}{4}&,\text{ if }0\le y <2\\
1&, \text{ if } y\ge2.
\end{cases}$$